# Failed to authenticate with public key in jenkins

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, jenkins

I am trying to deploy nodejs application using Jenkins, my application server is running under an EC2 instance.

My Jenkins application(deployment server) is running in another server.

### Steps I've done

1)Added new credentials with the `.pem` file of my application server.

2)Added my application server under `public over SSH`.

3) In the Jenkins project settings selected the option `Execute shell script on the remote host on ssh` and selected the host i've added in step 2.

When I try the build I am getting the following error

```
ERROR: Failed to authenticate with public key
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@298a385a
```